# How do you say “because” in Korean? Moreover, what are the differences and usages?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I understand that this is not an easy question to answer, so I am going to list the ones I've found.

1. ~어서, ~아서, ~어 and ~아
2. ~때문에, ~기 때문에 and ~기 때문이다
3. ~으니까, ~니까, ~으니 and ~니
4. ~ㄹ까 봐서, ~ㄹ까 봐, ~을까 봐서 and ~을까 봐
5. ~에 의해 and ~에 의해서
6. ~으로 인해서,  ~으로 인해, ~으로 인하여, ~로 인해서, ~로 인해 and ~로 인하여
7. ~다가 and ~다
8. ~ㄴ데, ~은데 and ~는데
9. ~다 보니, ~다 보니까 and ~다가 보니까
10. ~으므로 and ~므로
11. ~기에
12. ~길래
13. ~거든 and ~거든요
14. ~ㄹ 텐데 and ~을 텐데
15. ~ㄹ 테니까 and ~을 테니까
16. ~더니
17. ~느라고 and ~느라
18. ~는 바람에
19. ~ㄴ다고, ~는다고, ~이라고 and ~다고
20. 왜냐하면…~기 때문이다, 왜냐하면…~거든(요) and 왜냐하면…~(으)니까(요)

It astounds me that Korean has so many ways to say “because”, “so” and “therefore”. I don't think English has nearly as many!

So if there are any other expressions that I've missed, please don't hesitate to list them. Also, please tell me as many differences and usages as you can.

Comment: You're comparing an agglutinative language with a flexive (tending to isolating) one. It doesn't make much sense as many of those, especially suffixes, are composed from simpler oner.

Comment: English as just as many: so, this, to that end, to this end, hence, then, thus, accordingly, consequently, as a result, thereby, ergo, therefore, because, because of, just because, since, for, as, inasmuch as, 'cause, coz, cuz

Comment: I never thought there were so many of them like this even though I've spoken the language throughout my life lol.....

Comment: This is a good question. I upvoted. The thing is that they have differences and connotations that are quite difficult to describe briefly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the incomplete answer, I'll edit it time by time.
First, I think 13~16 doesn't mean 'because'.

For the rest of them, basically they have similar meaning but you have to distinguish the situations to use them.

For example, 20. 왜냐하면 should be used for formal writing. To use it informally, you can change it to 왜냐면.

6. 으로 인해서 (and variations of them) translates to 'due to~', and 5. 에 의해서 mostly translates to 'by ~'.
7. ~다 보니, 11. ~기에 and 12. ~길래 are related to time, like '네가 자길래 나도 잤어' can mean 'I saw you sleeping and I slept too'. And it feels like ~기에 is mostly used in writings.
8. ~다가 doesn't necessarily mean because. But It can imply it occasionally.
9. ~는 바람에 sounds like kind of informal, and blaming something. In the native dictionary, there are mostly negative examples using '~는 바람에'
10. ~한다고 ~는다고 seems to be used with progressive tense. And interchangable with ~하느라 ~느라

As a last comment, I think it's most common to use 1. ~아서, ~어서 in normal conversation, and 2. 때문에 or 20 왜냐하면 in common writing. Rest of them seems to have additional meaning that just 'because'.